# is it possible to extract all files in a directory to their respective folders?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, cmd.exe, winrar

So I've got a lot of .sbm files I zip and unzip on a regular basis. I generally use winrar gui and do by hand. I looked for a utility in the menus, but I've had no luck. So I was wondering if there's a way to extract (retaining their directory structure, and their folder names) all at once.

Comment: So you're just looking to extract all of the archived files at once, retaining their directory structure?  That is pretty basic to every archiving utility, generally the default action.  Can you describe what command or menu sequence you're using and what result you're getting?

Comment: I figured it out. I was insanely sleepy when I asked this. Should I close this? Or should I just post an answer?

Comment: Posting an answer would be great except the question also needs work so that it can be found in a search by someone else with whatever the issue is, and it makes sense when they find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so how one would do this is as followed: run the winrar GUI executable.
Navigate to the collection of files.
Select them all.
Right click.
Select extract to.
Select Extract Archives to sub folders.
Select OK.

Answer (score 2):

WinRAR has a right-click menu command called "extract each archive to separate folder". Select all zip files and right click on any one of them to get this option.

Comment: So they won't have all their contents extract to one folder, right?

Comment: For each archive, it creates a folder with the same name as the archive (without .zip) and extracts there.

Comment: Wait, this requires that I go to each one individually, and I'm trying to automate this.

Comment: OK, I just figured it out, I had to select extract archives to sub folders.

Comment: How does one add "Extract each archive to separate folder" to 7-zip's context menu? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the options tab and select "into their own folders".  It will create a subdirectory with the same name of each input compressed file.